# Begin with Sharepoint technology

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint technology. I don't have any idea where to start and how to proceed. So can anyone suggest me how I should proceed to know about the technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very open ended and will probably gather some criticism for being so but here's the 2 best suggestions I can provide you;

First - Read Books!

The first thing to understand is that Sharepoint comes in two flavours. You have the free to use Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS) which is the core of the product. This part is free and you can start developing using it right now! The second part is MOSS which is the commercial extensions of WSS. This contains loads of really cool features and additional controls such as the Content Query Webpart.

I'd recommend that you start with a good WSS book to understand the fundamentals. To this end I'd recommend [Inside Microsoft Windows Sharepoint Services](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=9692)

Second - Do the virtual labs. These allow you experiments with the main topics of Sharepoint in a controlled environment without even having to install or configure it yourself.

See: [Sharepoint Virtual Labs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs/bb512933)

Finally, here's a good site for covering some additional topics

[Microsoft Sharepoint References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/aa905692)

Comment: The book that you have mentioned I found very helpful. Thanks a lot @Brian.

Comment: @ANP: Great, I found the book a useful companion when starting out with Sharepoint too. However, make sure to check out the virtual labs as well, they're invaluable.